# log4j creating empty log files

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=All,consoleAppender, rollingFile

log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n  


log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=D:/home/tim/logs/sparkStreaming.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true
```

Using it in below code snippet

```
package rsvp;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import rsvp.util.LoadResourceFile;

import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.package$;

@Service
@ComponentScan({ "rsvp.util" })
public class ProcessingService {
    
    
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProcessingService.class); 
    

    @Autowired
    private final SparkConf sparkConf;
    
    @Autowired
    private LoadResourceFile AvroSchema;
    
    

    /*public ProcessingService() {
        this.sparkConf =  new SparkConf().setMaster("Local[*]").setAppName("RSVP");
    }
    */
    public ProcessingService(SparkConf sparkConf) {
        this.sparkConf = sparkConf;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            System.out.println("*************************STARTED******************************************************");
            SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder().config(this.sparkConf).getOrCreate();
             ss.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
            
            Dataset<Row> rsvpDT = ss.readStream().
                                    format(KafkaConstants.STREAM_FORMAT).
                                    option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KafkaConstants.KAFKA_BROKERS).
                                    option("subscribe", KafkaConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC).
                                    option("failOnDataLoss", false).
                                    load();

            System.out.println("Print Schema");
            rsvpDT.printSchema();
            System.out.println("show values*******************************88");
            
        
            /*
             * Dataset<Row> rsvpAndTimestampDF =
             * rsvpDT//selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)");
             * .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),
             * RSVpSchema.RSVP_SCHEMA).alias("rsvp")) .alias("meetup").select("meetup.*");
             */
            
            Dataset<Row> rsvpAvroDF = rsvpDT.select(package$.MODULE$.from_avro(col("value").cast("BINARY"), LoadResourceFile.AvroSchema)
                                      .alias("rsvp")).alias("meetup").select("meetup.*");

            /*
             * Dataset<Row> mySqlTableDS = dbExtract.readstudentTable();
             * mySqlTableDS.show();
             */

            StreamingQuery query = rsvpAvroDF.writeStream().outputMode(OutputMode.Update()).format("console")
                    .option("path", KafkaConstants.CHECKPOINT_LOCATION)
                    .option("checkpointLocation", KafkaConstants.CHECKPOINT_LOCATION).option("truncate", false)
                    .start();
           query.awaitTermination();
            ss.stop();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("**************ERROR OCCURED*******************" + e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Its creating empty log files, why is it ?  Am I using anything wrong ? want to keep appending logs in same log file.

Please suggest

Update: added whole code snippet using `try` and `catch` block

I'm already using try catch block, but still same issue coming where only `.error` is able to catch log and write in log file but no other appenders.

Any reason why ..?

Comment: First you are logging your error with `.debug(..)`, you should change that, to `.error(..)`. Additionally check if you have set the logging level accordingly to `debug` (it might be set to INFO, which is default for deployments)

Comment: @lunatikz, so it wont catch even If I use .debug(..) in my catch ? what's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using *ALL* as your log level, the problem is not with your `LOGGER.debug()` line off code.

The problem would be because you are not throwing an *Exception*.(It would be better if you add your *try* block too.)

Comment: Try to throw an Exception explicitly for example by   throw new Exception("Exception!!");
in first line of your try block, I think it is not catching any Exception at all

Comment: Plus you could try to explicitly load your *log4j.properties* using

    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

after you've initialized the *Logger* object.

Make sure *log4j.properties* is in search path used to load classes (E.g. src/main/resources)

Comment: I think the problem is in line 3 of your *try* block, where you are changing the log level to *ERROR*:
`ss.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");`